# Android Calendar DateFormat regional behavior

Tags: android, date, time, calendar

In my android application I get the time and the date with the following code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
String time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
```

In my Galaxy Note 4, I got:

- Date: 29.07.2016
- Time: 14:10:30

In Huawei Mate 8:

- Date: 29.07.2016
- Time: 02:10:30 nachm (what means pm).

On some customer devices it has some more formats.

So, my question is how can I get date and time on all devices and regions in the same format?

I want **dd.mm.yyyy** for date and **hh:mm:ss** for time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One options is `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat dataFormater = new SimpleDateFormat();

dataFormater.applyPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
String date = dataFormater.format(calendar.getTime());

dataFormater.applyPattern("hh:mm:ss");
String time = dataFormater.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: I updated the answer.. I wrongly used "mm" for month and minutes

Comment: Glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

I think date will be ok for you so You have to manually format the time from calendar like below.

```html
public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat TimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);

Calendar ATime = Calendar.getInstance();
String Timein12hourFormat = TimeFormat.format(ATime.getTime());
```

May this help you.Let me know.